# SQL divide hourly data into half hourly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, hour

I have a column which contains data from two separate sources - one set is pulled in at an hourly granularity and one by half hour.

```
Datetime           Source    Value  
01/01/2018 14:00   A          20
01/01/2018 14:00   B          15
01/01/2018 14:30   B          11
```

I would like to create a new column with the net of these on a half hourly basis.

```
Datetime           Net Value
01/01/2018 14:00   35              --20+15
01/01/2018 14:30   31              --20+11
```

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: What DB are you using? MSSQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL?

Comment: Should the second row in your example results be `14:30`?  Why doesn't it include the `15` value that has the same time stamp as the `20` it is including?

Comment: You have --20+15 which equals 35.... but where does the 20 come from?

Comment: @APH thanks, yes it should! I've edited it now. Tiredness = mistakes.

Comment: @Paolo using mysql. Server 2016

Comment: @aGuy the 20 is reported on an hourly basis but applies to both half hours with the hour..

Comment: Is creating a new view with just the hourly data divided into half hours the most straight forward solution? Then link it back to the original table and sum by half hour?

Comment: @cums . . . "mysql. Server 2016" does not refer to a specific product.  MySQL?  Or SQL Server 2016?

Comment: @Gordan Linoff my bad... SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just joining on date and hour, like this?

```
SELECT b.Datetime
    , ISNULL(a.val, 0) + ISNULL(b.val, 0)
FROM myTable b
JOIN myTable a
ON CAST(b.Datetime AS DATE) = CAST(a.Datetime AS DATE)
AND DATEPART(HOUR, b.Datetime) = DATEPART(HOUR, a.Datetime)
AND b.source = 'B' 
AND a.source = 'A'
```

From comments (thanks!): [try it in this DB Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=10d2789b763c5d308556a3112e011dd9)

Comment: Works good in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=10d2789b763c5d308556a3112e011dd9)

Comment: Thanks, APH - that worked a charm!
The data described above is applicable to several different 'units'. I've tried adding in an extra column for each unit and then running your query so that it runs for each unit separately - however, I'm getting an 'ambiguous column name' error...https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b97dcfc1fbe3e185504347172edf2f76
any thoughts? (that db fiddle site is brilliant BTW!)

Comment: @curns Since you're joining `MyTable` to itself, `unit` exists in both tables.  You have to specify which one you mean - either `a.unit` or `b.unit`

Comment: You will probably also need to add `a.unit = b.unit` to your join criteria - otherwise it will cause duplication that I think you do not want.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks a mill for your patience :)

Comment: Glad to help!  If this resolved your issue, please consider accepting the answer.